# Rails Modeling Auction App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modeling

I am having difficulty figuring out the proper association in modeling an 'item' within an auction app. Could the item could belong to many users since it could be auctioned off more than once? Does the item initially belong_to a single user or highest_bidder? etc.  Thank you in advance for your input

Answer (score 0):

It depends how generic the item in question is. If each item entry is a unique item as opposed to a type of item (Anchorman DVD as opposed to just DVD for instance) than you could have it belong to a single user. You can change that association over the course of the auction so that it belongs to the highest bidder at any given time. Past that it depends on what other functionality you'd like.

TLDR: belongs_to :user

Answer (score 0):

You could have an attribute for the item called highbidder_id which gets assigned a value only after the item is auctioned for. Each user could "has_many :items" as well.